# SyslogConfigurations API doesn't work for Python SDK

Tags: deepsecurity

For TrendMicro CloudOne, we'd like to gather some information from CloudOne console. One of these is Syslog configurations in place. I am using API reference and exact Python example from here:
https://cloudone.trendmicro.com/docs/workload-security/api-reference/tag/Syslog-Configurations#operation/listSyslogConfigurations

I use Python SDK mentioned here: https://cloudone.trendmicro.com/docs/workload-security/sdk-python/

But I get an error that SyslogConfigurationsApi is not present for the SDK:

```
  File "/Users/sebastiangradys/Development/C1/tenant_settings.py", line 89, in <module>
    api_instance = deepsecurity.SyslogConfigurationsApi(deepsecurity.ApiClient(configuration))
AttributeError: module 'deepsecurity' has no attribute 'SyslogConfigurationsApi'
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Please see a possible answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71258329/11149330).

Currently the SyslogConfigurationsApi is not in the SDK, but can be invoked manually via the `/syslogconfigurations` endpoint.